# How to fetch entries from multiple sections

Tags: entries, structure, craft.entries

I have five separate sections with x number of entries each. I would like to render all the entries from all the sections on a single entry template page. Is there a way to do this ? I know we can set entries like this  `{% set entries = craft.entries.section('sectionHandle').limit(10) %}` , but I'm not sure how to get entries from all the sections.

Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can insert an array of different sections instead of a single one to pull entries from multiple sections

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section(['sectionHandle', 'sectionHandleTwo']).limit(10) %}
```

You can also write that

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({
  section: ['sectionHandle', 'sectionHandleTwo'],
  limit: 10
}) %}
```

If you remove the `.section()` / `section:...,` entirely you'll fetch all entries from all sections. 
Here's a link to the [docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#parameter-value-syntax)